# What data are safe to publish from the "config.log" and what not?

Tags: ruby

I am totally new to programming world and I don't succeed in finding a solution to download Ruby.

The question I asked isn't answered so far. Therefore I want to publish my config.log. But I really dunno if it is safe to publish all from the config.log.

Can anyone tell me what is safe to publish?

Well maybe it is dangerous but this is the config.log and I at least deleted my computer name:

TThis file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure --prefix=/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl

### ---------

### Platform.

### ---------

hostname = MacBook-Pro-van-J.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 18.6.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 402 tasks, 1379 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.90, Mach factor: 2.09
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//.rbenv/shims
PATH: /Users//anaconda3/bin
PATH: /Users//anaconda3/condabin
PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin

### -----------

### Core tests.

### -----------

configure:2996: checking for ruby
configure:3014: found /usr/bin/ruby
configure:3027: result: /usr/bin/ruby
configure:3105: checking build system type
configure:3119: result: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
configure:3207: checking host system type
configure:3220: result: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
configure:3240: checking target system type
configure:3253: result: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
configure:3905: checking for C compiler version
configure:3914: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang --version >&5
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users//anaconda3/bin
configure:3925: $? = 0
configure:3914: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -v >&5
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users//anaconda3/bin
configure:3925: $? = 0
configure:3914: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -V >&5
clang-4.0: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang-4.0: error: no input files
configure:3925: $? = 1
configure:3914: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -qversion >&5
clang-4.0: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang-4.0: error: no input files
configure:3925: $? = 1
configure:3945: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3967: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe  -I/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -L/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs conftest.c  >&5
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3971: $? = 1
configure:4009: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4014: error: in `/var/folders/19/1hf7txt144z0k3flz7fy50y40000gn/T/ruby-build.20190610140025.11270/ruby-2.6.3':
configure:4016: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See`config.log' for more details

### ----------------

### Cache variables.

### ----------------

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe '
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-I/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value='-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++14 -fmessage-length=0'
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_cflags_set=
ac_cv_env_cflags_value=
ac_cv_env_cppflags_set=
ac_cv_env_cppflags_value=
ac_cv_env_cxxflags_set=
ac_cv_env_cxxflags_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
ac_cv_path_BASERUBY=/usr/bin/ruby
ac_cv_prog_CC=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0

### -----------------

### Output variables.

### -----------------

ALLOCA=''
AR='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar'
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
ARFLAGS=''
AS='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-as'
ASFLAGS=''
ASMEXT=''
BASERUBY='/usr/bin/ruby --disable=gems'
BOOTSTRAPRUBY=''
BTESTRUBY=''
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CC_VERSION=''
CC_VERSION_MESSAGE=''
CC_WRAPPER=''
CFLAGS='-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe '
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
CONFIGURE=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-I/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9'
CPPOUTFILE=''
CROSS_COMPILING=''
CSRCFLAG=''
CXX='x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++'
CXXFLAGS='-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++14 -fmessage-length=0'
DEFS=''
DESTDIR=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLDSHARED=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DLNOBJ=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
DTRACE=''
DTRACE_EXT=''
DTRACE_OBJ=''
DTRACE_OPT=''
DTRACE_REBUILD=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_DEBUG_ENV=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
ENCOBJS=''
ENCSTATIC=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTDLDFLAGS=''
EXTLDFLAGS=''
EXTOBJS=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GIT='git'
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
HAVE_BASERUBY='yes'
HAVE_GIT='yes'
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTALL_STATIC_LIBRARY=''
LD='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ld'
LDFLAGS='-L/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs'
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_A_OBJS=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBRUBY_SONAME=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='2'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MATHN=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='6'
MJIT_CC=''
MJIT_CFLAGS=''
MJIT_DEBUGFLAGS=''
MJIT_HEADER_FLAGS=''
MJIT_HEADER_INSTALL_DIR=''
MJIT_LDSHARED=''
MJIT_OPTFLAGS=''
MJIT_SUPPORT=''
MKDIR_P=''
NM='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-nm'
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_DIR=''
POSTLINK=''
PRELOADENV=''
PREP=''
RANLIB='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ranlib'
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_API_VERSION='$(MAJOR).$(MINOR)'
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_EXEC_PREFIX=''
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_LIB_VERSION=''
RUBY_LIB_VERSION_STYLE=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='2.6.3'
RUBY_SEARCH_PATH=''
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUBY_VERSION_NAME='${RUBY_BASE_NAME}-${ruby_version}'
RUNRUBY=''
RUNRUBY_COMMAND=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOEXT=''
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP='/Users//anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-strip'
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='3'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCC_WRAPPER=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
X_FIBER_COROUTINE_H=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_NM=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
ac_ct_RANLIB=''
arch=''
archincludedir=''
archlibdir=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin18.6.0'
build_vendor='apple'
cflags=''
codesign=''
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dsymutil=''
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin18.6.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libdirname=''
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.3'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyarchdir=''
rubyarchhdrdir=''
rubyarchprefix=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubysitearchprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitearchdir=''
sitearchhdrdir=''
sitearchincludedir=''
sitearchlibdir=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sitelibdir=''
strict_warnflags=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin18'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin18'
target_vendor='apple'
try_header=''
vendorarchdir=''
vendorarchhdrdir=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
vendorlibdir=''
warnflags=''

### -----------

### confdefs.h.

### -----------

/* confdefs.h */

## define PACKAGE_NAME ""

## define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""

## define PACKAGE_VERSION ""

## define PACKAGE_STRING ""

## define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""

## define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with the question - you might want to format the code - either with code or pre blocks, or triple backticks for git style code fences. It would help readability hugely. I'd help, but I can't tell if all of this is the output of a single command

Comment: What I mean to say is, is there any data in an ordinary config.log that shouldn't be posted in a question from safety point of view?